# How to enable auto currency conversion in multiple websites in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency, currency-rates

I am using Magento community edition 1.9.1.0. I have set up two websites: USD and NRS (Nepalese rupee). I have also set up the base currency for both the stores respectively. The default currency in default store config is NRS. What I want to achieve is, once I enter a product, the currency gets converted accordingly for both the websites. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is mean by `the currency gets converted accordingly for both the websites`

Comment: but if you change the store view the currency gets converted to the one that you assigned in the certain store.

Comment: Magento does this automatically for you, you only need to load the websites. Each website will hold the prices in their default currency.

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz I have loaded the websites and appropriate currency is also displayed. But the problem is, if the price of a product is NRS 70,000 in NRS website then the price remains same in USD website and is displayed 70,000 USD. The auto conversion is not working or may be I am unaware of how to do it. Could you please suggest something?

Comment: @AmitBera Kindly refer to my previous comment.

Comment: Please take these steps, go to system->configuration->catalog->catalog->price and set the catalog price scope to website. Now change the price of products for US store to US price. And then check if it works.

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz Thanks for the reply. When I set the price scope to Global (not website) it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the currency rates saved. Go to System->Manage Currency->Rates. Then click the import button and save